# JSON Header "Content-Type" is not allowed

Tags: json, syntax-error, roblox, luau

I have this code for Luau and I have been trying to solve this for a minute but my research has no end and no solution in sight. I send a signal through a remote and a local script with a string attached to it, someone help me or point me in a good direction.

```
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")

local webhookUrl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1119845072826023966/pklwq1jIrkwhv0XQjYSQxOu2hX0HD8qRjzT8-pP1ILPNo4-MD9vgJlQ2ktuEaLyUhreC"

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").DiscordMessageRemote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, message)
    local jsonMessage = HttpService:JSONEncode(message)

    local headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] = "message/json"
    }

    local success, response = pcall(function()
        return HttpService:PostAsync(webhookUrl, jsonMessage, Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson, false, headers)
    end)

    if success then
        print("Webhook message sent successfully!")
    else
        print("Failed to send webhook message:", response)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the content-type header?